# meter datos acumulados en un state en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo duda en como meter datos acumulados en react usando hooks dentro de un useEffect filtrando especificamente solo el id.

```
import {groups} from '../../database/groups';    
const [candidate, setCandidate] = useState({})

   useEffect(() => {
      groups.forEach(({id}) => {
         setCandidate({
            ...candidate,
            id
         })
         
      });
      
   }, [])
```

así es la data.

```
groups = [{
  id:"pan-anaya",
    "candidato": "RICARDO ANAYA CORTES",
    "partido": "PARTIDO ACCION NACIONAL",
  imagen: "pan.png",
    alt: "imagen del pan"
},
{
  id:"pri-meade",
    "candidato": "JOSE ANTONIO MEADE KURIBREÑA",
    "partido": "PARTIDO REVOLUCIONARIO INSTITUCIONAL",
  imagen: "pri.png",
    alt: "imagen del pri "
},]
```

El problema es que solo quedan los datos así, es decir solo mete el ultimo dato:

```
{id: 'pri-meade'}
   id: "pri-meade"
   [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Cuando dices datos acumulados, te refieres a popular un arreglo?

Comment: si popular significa andar metiendo los datos como si fuera un push si

Comment: candidate no es un arreglo, es un objeto. Por eso no te funciona. Además, si necesitas meter todo lo de group dentro de tu state, porque simplemente no inicializas tu state con group de una vez?

Comment: a perdon el objeto en si es asi y solo queria el id pero elimine lo demas porque lo queria simplificar {
      id:"pan-anaya",
  "candidato": "RICARDO ANAYA CORTES",
  "partido": "PARTIDO ACCION NACIONAL",
      imagen: "pan.png",
  alt: "imagen del pan"
 },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes, si el arreglo de `groups` que estás importando lo necesitas alojar en un estado local de tu componente tienes varios errores:

```
// Si el arreglo groups que importas contiene la siguiente estructura:
const groups = candidate = [{
  id: 'pan-anaya',
  name: 'Pan-Anaya'
}, {
  id: 'pri-meade',
  name: 'Pri-Meade'
}]

// Cambia el objeto vacío inicial ({}) de tu estado local por un arreglo vacio ([])
const [candidate, setCandidate] = useState([])

// Luego en tu useEffect como componentDidMount
useEffect(() => {
  // Creamos un nuevo arreglo que solo nos retorne el id
  const newGroups = groups.map((group) => group.id)
  setCandidate(...newGroups )
}, [])
```

Ya deberías poder visualizar tu estado local `candidate` como un arreglo con los valores:

```
candidate = [{
  id: 'pan-anaya'
}, {
  id: 'pri-meade',
}]
```

Comment: si esta bien, pero me equivoque yo porque lo que queria era filtrar informacion que yo no puse pero que esta dentro de candidate  que no lo quiero en el estado por ejemplo: {
      id:"pan-anaya",
  "candidato": "RICARDO ANAYA CORTES",
  "partido": "PARTIDO ACCION NACIONAL",
      imagen: "pan.png",
  alt: "imagen del pan"
 },

Comment: solo quiero el id

Comment: Agrega la aclaración de solo querer el id en tu pregunta y ya edito mi respuesta para que te sirva :)

Comment: ya esta editado gracias :).

Comment: @YahirAntonio listo, ya edité mi respuesta, espero te sirva

Comment: de pura casualidad, ¿No te ha dado un problema con este tipo de inicialización de datos?, es que en la variable newGroups si me aparecen todos los datos, pero cuando hago un console.log(candidate), ya sea afuera o adentro del useEffect, solo me aparece el primero, esto 'pan-anaya', no me aparece como si fuera un arreglo.

Comment: a ya lo arregle, faltaba poner esto setCandidate([...newGroups ]), los corchetes.